# Displaying a list in a tabbed android program

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I have a program with 3 tabs and I'm unable to get it to display correctly in the second slot.  I have been able to display something fine under the other tabs but the list eludes me.  I have gotten it to work on its own without tabs so if someone can tell me why it won't display as a part of a swipable tab based program that would help.

list_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/shiftid"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/datetime"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/starttime"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/endtime"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

listmain_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FAA000">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

ListActivity.java // this is so it will recognize it as a tab page

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ListActivity extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listmain_layout, container, false);
    return view;
}
}
```

ListViewAdapter.java //Where I establish the hashmap

```
import static onyx.shiftcreator.Constants.FIRST_COLUMN;
import static onyx.shiftcreator.Constants.SECOND_COLUMN;
import static onyx.shiftcreator.Constants.THIRD_COLUMN;
import static onyx.shiftcreator.Constants.FOURTH_COLUMN;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
Activity activity;
TextView txtFirst;
TextView txtSecond;
TextView txtThird;
TextView txtFourth;
public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){
    super();
    this.activity=activity;
    this.list=list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    LayoutInflater inflater=activity.getLayoutInflater();

    if(convertView == null){

        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);

        txtFirst=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.shiftid);
        txtSecond=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.datetime);
        txtThird=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.starttime);
        txtFourth=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.endtime);

    }

    HashMap<String, String> map=list.get(position);
    txtFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
    txtSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
    txtThird.setText(map.get(THIRD_COLUMN));
    txtFourth.setText(map.get(FOURTH_COLUMN));

    return convertView;
 }

 }
```

ListDisplay.java  // Where I load and display contents of Hashmap

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListDisplay extends Activity {

private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listmain_layout);

    ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    HashMap<String,String> temp=new HashMap<String, String>();
    temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, "Ankit Karia");
    temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, "Male");
    temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, "22");
    temp.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, "Unmarried");
    list.add(temp);

    HashMap<String,String> temp2=new HashMap<String, String>();
    temp2.put(FIRST_COLUMN, "Rajat Ghai");
    temp2.put(SECOND_COLUMN, "Male");
    temp2.put(THIRD_COLUMN, "25");
    temp2.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, "Unmarried");
    list.add(temp2);

    HashMap<String,String> temp3=new HashMap<String, String>();
    temp3.put(FIRST_COLUMN, "Karina Kaif");
    temp3.put(SECOND_COLUMN, "Female");
    temp3.put(THIRD_COLUMN, "31");
    temp3.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, "Unmarried");
    list.add(temp3);

    ListViewAdapter adapter=new ListViewAdapter(this, list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id)
        {
            int pos=position+1;
            Toast.makeText(ListDisplay.this, Integer.toString(pos)+" Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });

 }
 }
```

MainActivity.java  //Where I establish the page location under a tab Main manages the actionbar

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        //return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        if(position == 0)
            return new SyncActivity();
        if(position == 1)
            return new ListActivity();
        if(position == 2)
            return new EntryActivity();


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment, you have to set the list and its adapter, like so:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, container, false);
    lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.listviewlayout, new ArrayList<YourObject>());
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
return  rootView;
```

You will still have to populate the list. This can be done as normal with an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest to switch from Activity to ListActivity. This could simplify your layout. To be exact you don't need any layout for the list itself. Same applies to Fragment. If it should only show a list use ListFragment.